# Which of WordPress's .php files need to be directly accessible via HTTP?

Tags: urls, security

I'm trying to tighten up security on my WordPress installation, and one of the things that seems like it might be a good idea is preventing all of the internal-use .php files from being accessed directly via HTTP.  For instance, `http://MYSITE/blog/xmlrpc.php` needs to remain directly accessible, but there's no reason why `http://MYSITE/blog/wp-load.php` shouldn't give a 404.

The question is: Where do I get a *complete* list of stock Wordpress .php files that can legitimately appear in URLs?

Also, I use mod_rewrite to remove the top-level `index.php` from all my published URLs -- does that mean I can block direct use of `http://MYSITE/blog/index.php?whatever`?

Comment: This is answered in a newer duplicate: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/415832/which-php-files-in-a-wordpress-setup-do-not-need-direct-web-access/418142

Comment: Confirming @IanDunn: your answer to that question is exactly what I was looking for 11 years ago (well, except that it doesn't address the final paragraph of this question, but that's minor).

Answer (score -1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but far as I know, You don't access directly to any of the files, the apache user does. Meaning, the user browser talks to the server's httpd process which will get the file from the filesystem.
So, i think that if you get a 404 on the browser when directly requesting a file, you will get the same 404 error when using the links on the wordpress pages.

I understand your point, I just don't know if it is possible.

About blocking requests based on the address, I think you should look at the specs of the .htaccess file. The Wordpress uses this file to config the permalinks.

Comment: Right, any .php file that can appear in a hyperlink needs to be accessible via HTTP.  But the vast majority of Wordpress's .php files are only used via `require`-type statements in the PHP code, which bypasses the web server's access permissions.  Those files don't need to be valid HTTP GET destinations, and it might improve security to prevent them.  I know how to write an `.htaccess` file that blocks access to files, I just need the list of .php files that *shouldn't* be denied.

Comment: Correcting you, because you're wrong.  When you visit `http://mysite.url/` you're really accessing `http://mysite.url/index.php` directly.  Also in the admin, you access `/wp-admin/index.php` directly.  When viewing post lists you access `/wp-admin/edit.php` directly.  Etc ...